# Python: List merging method

Tags: python-3.x, list, merge

I have a question:

I have 2 lists:

```
list_1 = [1, 2, 3]
list_2 = [4, 5, 6]
```

And I want to merge them in order to have the following result:

```
mergedlist = [1, 4, 2, 5, 3, 6]
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
mergedlist = list_1 + list_2
```

If you want that specific order in `mergedlist`:

```
mergedlist = []
for i, entry in enumerate(list_1):
    mergedlist.extend([entry, list_2[i]])
```

Comment: That's a good iterative way, check my answer if you like to see another solut. Plus one btw

Answer (score 0):

You can use chain from iter tools:

```
list_1 = [1, 2, 3]
list_2 = [4, 5, 6]

from itertools import chain

res = list(chain.from_iterable((list_1[x], list_2[x]) for x in range(len(list_1))))
```

=> [1, 4, 2, 5, 3, 6]

Comment: `zip(list_1, list_2)` works as well

Comment: @Wondercricket haha suuuuuure, why I didn't think about that??? so simple... you should post it as answer

Comment: Because Kshitij Saraogi beat me to it :)

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the most Pythonic way would be:

`merged_list = [item for pair in zip(list_1, list_2) for item in pair]`

Alternatively, you can use [`collections.chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) as well:

`merged_list = list(chain.from_iterable(zip(list_1, list_2)))`